# BottomSheetDialogFragment result to fragment which started it

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to listen or pass data from a BottomSheetDialogFragment into Fragment to change something on the Fragment, on the button click I show BottomSheetDialogFragmentin in Homefragment and BottomSheetDialogFragmentwill do API call and on the success, it will dismiss BottomSheetDialogFragment and do second API call which is in Homefragment and on the second API call success I am making textview visibility gone in Homefragment which gives me NullpointerException

**BottomSheetDialogFragment**

```
 public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements LoginViewInteractor {

    public static final String TAG = "BottomSheetFragment";


    @BindView(R.id.edittext)
    EditText edittext;

    @BindView(R.id.zero_txt)
    CardView zero_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.one_txt)
    CardView one_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.two_txt)
    CardView two_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.three_txt)
    CardView three_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.four_txt)
    CardView four_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.five_txt)
    CardView five_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.six_txt)
    CardView six_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.seven_txt)
    CardView seven_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.eight_txt)
    CardView eight_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.nine_txt)
    CardView nine_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.clear)
    RelativeLayout clear;

    @BindView(R.id.next_btn)
    ShadowLayout next_btn;

    @BindView(R.id.clearImage)
    ImageView clearImage;

    @BindView(R.id.nic_logo)
    ImageView nic_logo;

    @BindView(R.id.enter_pin_txt)
    TextView enter_pin_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.close)
    ImageView close;

    @Inject
    ViewUtil viewUtil;

    @Inject
    PreferenceUtil preferenceUtil;

    @Inject
    LoginPresenter loginPresenter;

    @Inject
    DialogUtil dialogUtil;
    Dialog dialog;
    int pin_count;
    Button button;
    int length;

    String serviceName;
    Context context;

    public BottomSheetFragment() {
    }

    public BottomSheetFragment(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // this is for rounded bottom sheet dialog
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pin_view, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Injector.component().inject(this);

        loginPresenter.attachViewInteractor(this);

        edittext.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);

        edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                edittext.setLetterSpacing(0.8f);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (s.length() >= 4) {
                    next_btn.setClickable(true);
                    next_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    next_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> onClickNextBtn());
                } else {
                    next_btn.setClickable(false);
                    next_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                if (count >= 1 || s.length() >= 1) {
                    clear.setClickable(true);
                    clearImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (count == 0) {
                    clear.setClickable(false);
                    edittext.setLetterSpacing(0.2f);
                    clearImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    clear.setClickable(true);
                    clearImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        customKeyboard();

        close.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            BottomSheetFragment.super.onDismiss(getDialog());
        });
    }

    public void customKeyboard() {
        one_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("1");
        });
        two_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("2");
        });

        three_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("3");
        });

        four_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("4");
        });
        five_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("5");
        });
        six_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("6");
        });
        seven_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("7");
        });
        eight_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("8");
        });
        nine_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("9");
        });
        zero_txt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.append("0");
        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            length = edittext.getText().length();

            if (length > 0) {
                edittext.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
            }
        });

        clear.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            edittext.getText().clear();
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void onClickNextBtn() {

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.nicloader)
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)).into(nic_logo);

        enter_pin_txt.setText("Please wait...");

        clearImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        clear.setClickable(false);
        next_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        clear.setClickable(false);

        loginPresenter.onLogin(edittext.getText().toString());

        loginPresenter.onLogin(edittext.getText().toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(NicAsiaResponseModel<LoginResponseParams> response) {

        if (response.getStatus().equals("SUCCESS")) {

            onDismiss(getDialog());     // on Success dismiss BottomSheetDialogFragment

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailed(NicAsiaResponseModel<LoginResponseParams> response) {
        if (response.getStatus().equals("INVALID_PASSWORD")) {

            pin_count++;

            if (pin_count == 1) {
                dialog = dialogUtil.setDialog(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_pin_txt1), getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_pin_txt2), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wrong_pin));
                button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.common_pop_up_btn);
                button.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.dismiss());
                nic_logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logonica);
                enter_pin_txt.setText("Enter PIN Number");
                edittext.setText("");

            } else if (pin_count == 2) {
                dialog = dialogUtil.setDialog(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_pin_txt1), getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_pin_txt3), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wrong_pin));
                button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.common_pop_up_btn);
                button.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.dismiss());
                dialog.findViewById(R.id.text3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nic_logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logonica);
                enter_pin_txt.setText("Enter PIN Number");
                edittext.setText("");
            }
        } else if (response.getStatus().equals("USER_BLOCKED")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountBlockedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        System.out.println(response.getStatusDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkCallProgress() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkCallCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onHTTPError(int httpCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkCallError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        if (serviceName.equals(Config.Get_Balance_Wallet)) {
            new HomeFragment().makeApiCall();                 //Calling Second Api call which is in HomeFragmengt
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment**

```
  public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements GetBalanceViewInteractor {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

    @BindView(R.id.horizontalScrollView1)
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView1;

    @BindView(R.id.dashboard_txt_layout)
    ConstraintLayout dashboard_txt_layout;

    @BindView(R.id.greeting_txt)
    TextView greeting_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.user_name)
    TextView user_name;

    @BindView(R.id.dashboard_txt1)
    TextView dashboard_txt1;

    @BindView(R.id.view_balance)
    Button view_balance;

    @BindView(R.id.wallet_balance)
    LinearLayout wallet_balance;

    @BindView(R.id.wallet_balance_txt)
    TextView wallet_balance_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.saving_acct_balance_refresh_btn)
    ImageView saving_acct_balance_refresh_btn;

    @BindView(R.id.fd_acct_bal_refresh_btn)
    ImageView fd_acct_bal_refresh_btn;

    @BindView(R.id.wallet_card)
    CardView wallet_card;

    @BindView(R.id.wallet_acct_num)
    TextView wallet_acct_num;

    @BindView(R.id.saving_card)
    CardView saving_card;

    @BindView(R.id.saving_acct_num)
    TextView saving_acct_num;

    @BindView(R.id.fd_card)
    CardView fd_card;

    @BindView(R.id.others_acct_num)
    TextView others_acct_num;

    @BindView(R.id.scorllview)
    ScrollView scorllview;

    @BindView(R.id.dashboard1)
    ConstraintLayout dashboard1;

    @BindView(R.id.my_account)
    CardView my_account;

    @BindView(R.id.load_money)
    CardView load_money;

    @BindView(R.id.wallet_acct_txt)
    TextView wallet_acct_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.savings_acct_txt)
    TextView savings_acct_txt;

    @BindView(R.id.wallet_acct_balance_refresh_btn)
    ImageView wallet_acct_balance_refresh_btn;

    @Inject
    PreferenceUtil preferenceUtil;

    @Inject
    Gson gson;

    @Inject
    DialogUtil dialogUtil;

    Dialog dialog;

    ImageView close_pin;

    int scrollX, scrollY;

    BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment;

    @Inject
    GetBalancePresenter getBalancePresenter;

    Animation animation;

    String wallet_amt;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Injector.component().inject(this);

        getBalancePresenter.attachViewInteractor(this);


        if (preferenceUtil.readBoolean(Config.WALLET_ACCT, false) == true) {
            wallet_card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            wallet_acct_txt.setText(preferenceUtil.readString(Config.WALLET_ACCT_TYPE, ""));
            wallet_acct_num.setText(preferenceUtil.readString(Config.WALLET_ACCT_NUM, ""));
        }
        if (preferenceUtil.readBoolean(Config.SAVINGS_ACCT, false) == true) {
            saving_card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            savings_acct_txt.setText(preferenceUtil.readString(Config.SAVINGS_ACCT_TYPE, ""));
            saving_acct_num.setText(preferenceUtil.readString(Config.SAVINGS_ACCT_NUM, ""));
        }
        if (preferenceUtil.readBoolean(Config.OTHERS_ACCT, false) == true) {
            fd_card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate);

        horizontalScrollView1.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
        scorllview.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);


        wallet_acct_balance_refresh_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> showBottomSheet(Config.Get_Balance_Wallet));

        view_balance.setOnClickListener(v -> showBottomSheet(Config.Get_Balance_Wallet));

        saving_acct_balance_refresh_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> saving_acct_balance_refresh_btn.startAnimation(animation));
        fd_acct_bal_refresh_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> fd_acct_bal_refresh_btn.startAnimation(animation));

        scorllview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> {
            scrollY = scorllview.getScrollY();

            if (scorllview.getScaleY() > 10) {
                dashboard1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_transparent_color1));
            } else if (scorllview.getScaleY() > 90) {
                dashboard1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_transparent_color2));
            } else if (scorllview.getScaleY() > 160) {
                dashboard1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        });

        horizontalScrollView1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> {

            scrollX = horizontalScrollView1.getScrollX();

            if (horizontalScrollView1.getScrollX() > 0) {
                dashboard_txt_layout.setElevation(0);
            } else {
                dashboard_txt_layout.setElevation(1);
            }

            if (scrollX >= 30 && scrollX <= 100) {
                // updateKyctxt.setAlpha(0.9f);
                greeting_txt.setAlpha(0.6f);
                user_name.setAlpha(0.6f);
                dashboard_txt1.setAlpha(0.6f);
            } else if (scrollX >= 100 && scrollX <= 240) {
                // updateKyctxt.setAlpha(0.0f);
                greeting_txt.setAlpha(0.3f);
                user_name.setAlpha(0.3f);
                dashboard_txt1.setAlpha(0.3f);
            } else if (scrollX >= 240) {
                // updateKyctxt.setAlpha(0.0f);
                greeting_txt.setAlpha(0.0f);
                user_name.setAlpha(0.0f);
                dashboard_txt1.setAlpha(0.0f);
            } else if (scrollX == 0) {
                // updateKyctxt.setAlpha(1.0f);
                greeting_txt.setAlpha(1.0f);
                user_name.setAlpha(1.0f);
                dashboard_txt1.setAlpha(1.0f);
            }
        });

        my_account.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(MyAccount.class, null));

        load_money.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(LoadMoneyActivity.class, null));

    }

    public void showBottomSheet(String serviceName) {
        bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment(serviceName);
        bottomSheetFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), BottomSheetFragment.TAG);
    }


    @Override
    public void onGetBalanceSuccess(NicAsiaResponseModel<GetBalanceResponseParams> response) {

        GetBalanceResponseParams openBasicAccountResponseParams = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(response.getResponseParams()), GetBalanceResponseParams.class);

        if (response.getStatus().equals("SUCCESS")) {
            preferenceUtil.save("Wallet_Balance_success", true);
            preferenceUtil.save("Wallet_Balance", openBasicAccountResponseParams.getAvailableBalance());
            wallet_amt = openBasicAccountResponseParams.getAvailableBalance();
            view_balance.setVisibility(View.GONE);                            //  here i get Nullpointerexception
            wallet_balance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            wallet_balance_txt.setText("NPR" + openBasicAccountResponseParams.getAvailableBalance());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetBalanceFailed(NicAsiaResponseModel<GetBalanceResponseParams> response) {
        System.out.println(response.getStatusDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkCallProgress() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkCallCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onHTTPError(int httpCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkCallError(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void makeApiCall() {                             // Second Api call method
        Injector.component().inject(this);
        getBalancePresenter.attachViewInteractor(this);
        GetBalanceParams getBalanceParams = new GetBalanceParams();
        getBalanceParams.setAccountNo(preferenceUtil.readString(Config.WALLET_ACCT_NUM, ""));
        getBalancePresenter.onGetBalance(getBalanceParams);
    }

 }
```